# How to receive LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN in CListCtrl?

Tags: clistctrl

I have a class inherited from CListCtrl. Why I didn't receive any message for LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN in the method OnNotify() of my class when clicking and dragging???

I overwrote the method OnNotify() in my class and tried to reveive LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN. But it didn't work...

```
BOOL CListCtrlEx::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* 
pResult) 
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pnmv = (LPNMLISTVIEW)lParam;

    switch(pnmv->hdr.code){
        case LVN_MARQUEEBEGIN: 
        ; // Deal with some case here.
        break;
    }

    return CListCtrl::OnNotify(wParam, lParam, pResult);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you receive other notify messages, like `LVN_ITEMACTIVATE` ?

Comment: If not, possibly message map entry is missing

Comment: Only received one message TTN_GETDISPINFOW when moved mouse into the dialog which contains my CListCtrlEx object.

Comment: Does `MESSAGE_MAP` contain your handler?